# If $gh=hg$ and $\rho$ is a representation of $G$, then the matrices $\rho(g)$ and $\rho(h)$ are simulatenously diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $|G|=n$, and $g,h\in G$ such that $gh=hg$. If $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation, where $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$,  prove that there exists a basis of $V$ in which both $\rho(g)$ and $\rho(h)$ are diagonal.

I could prove this result using general methods of **linear algebra**, as follows:

Since $G$ is finite, $|G|=n$,  it follows that $\rho(g)^n =\rho(g^n) = \rho(1) = I$. If $p(X) = X^n-1,$ the condition before shows us that $p(\rho(g))=0$, which ensures that the minimal polynomial for $\rho(g)$ must divide $X^n-1$. Now, $X^n-1$ has no repeated roots and therefore so does the minimal polynomial. We conclude from this that $\rho(g)$ is diagonalizable.

The same argument runs for $\rho(h)$. Now, both are diagonalizable and commuting. By linear algebra, they are simultaneously diagonalizable.

My question is: **is there a way to prove this claim using only representation theory methods?** or a proof which is heavily based on representation theory methods?

Comment: WLOG $G=\langle a,b\rangle$, and so $G$ is abelian. Hence every conjugacy class has but one element, and so there are $|G|$ irreducible representations of $G$, and so all are $1$-dimensional. So $V$ is the sum of $1$-dimensional representations. But really, what's the use of Lin Alg if we don't use it?

Answer (score 0):

Since $G$ is abelian, then every irreducible representation is 1-dimensional. By Maschke's Theorem ($G$ is finite), every finite-dimensional representation is semisimple, hence every representation of $G$ is a direct sum of 1-dimensional representations $V=\mathbb{C}v_1\oplus...\oplus \mathbb{C}v_n$. It follows $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a common basis of $\rho(g)$ for all $g\in G$.